# Cross-browser align text in td and button value in td

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, button, internet-explorer-9

I wish to define css details in order to align plain text in td and button value text in td, so that they align in any browser type, or most of them at the least.

Below is my trial and the differences in rendering in IE9/8/7 and Chrome. As you can see, the given html looks OK in IE9, but IE8/IE7 and Chrome are wrong. Adding padding (directly in text td or to an added div in the text td) will not solve this, because then IE9 will be wrong.

So what css definition should be used to ensure that in all browsers the plain text and button value text are aligned properly?

[image: IE9] [image: IE8] [image: IE7] [image: Chrome]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: solid black 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    td {
        border-style: dotted solid none none;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    input.example {
        color: blue;
        background: white;
        padding-top:1px;
        padding-left:0px;
        border: 0px;
        outline:0;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p/>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>EXAMPLE</td>
               <td><input type="button" class="example" value="EXAMPLE"></td>
            </tr>
            Chrome
         </tbody>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the suggestion done by Ben, eventually I found the best solution to this pesky little problem. First I tried following his suggestion as is, but as a stylish version: I tried removing `vertical-align: top;` from css td and adding `style="valign: top;"` to the td elements. At first I thought that was the way to go because now  the alignment was OK in IE7/Chrome and off just a little in IE8/IE9, but then I realized that `valign` is a deprecated attribute and a non-existing sub-value in the style attribute.
Hence I had to look further, and landed up in doing sort of an after-burner javascript where I adjust padding-top in various browsers. I had to do the following adjustments:

- css input.example: padding-top 0px; height: 14px;
- IE7/quirks/Opera: for all previous sibling-td's set property style.paddingTop to 1px;
- IE8/IE9: do nothing
- Firefox: for all previous sibling-td's set property style.paddingTop to 2px;

html (note that Opera and Firefox use a different DOM as opposed to IE, manifesting itself in a different method to get the previous sibling):

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: solid black 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    td {
        border-style: dotted solid none none;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    input.example {
        color: blue;
        background: white;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        border: 0px;
        outline:0;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 14px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p/>
    <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>EXAMPLE</td>
           <td><input type="button" class="example" value="EXAMPLE"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // use personal custom javascript function to determine browser version
        switch (browser.version()) {
            case "MSIE 7.0":
                var elts = getElementsByClassName('example');
                for (var i=0; i < elts.length; i++) {
                    node = elts[i].parentNode;
                    while (node = node.previousSibling) {
                        node.style.paddingTop = "1px";
                    };
                }
                break;
            case "Opera/9.80":
                var elts = getElementsByClassName('example');
                for (var i=0; i < elts.length; i++) {
                    node = elts[i].parentNode;
                    while (node = node.previousElementSibling) {
                        node.style.paddingTop = "1px";
                    };
                }
                break;
            case "Firefox/10.0":
                var elts = getElementsByClassName('example');
                for (var i=0; i < elts.length; i++) {
                    node = elts[i].parentNode;
                    while (node = node.previousElementSibling) {
                        node.style.paddingTop = "2px";
                    };
                }
                break;
            default:
                // do nothing
        }
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as alignment goes inside a TD, your best bet is to use the `valign` property of TD. Specify `valign="top"` inside the TD tags, so that no matter how big each TD element is, it will always stick to the top.

As far as other alignments, I find image and button aligning dreadful for cross browser support, but you can specify the `vertical-align` css property as well.

Ex:

```
img,input{
vertical-align: middle
}
```

and

```
<td valign="top">EXAMPLE</td>
<td valign="top"><input type="button" class="example" value="EXAMPLE"></td>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Yes that's already in the css td defs: `vertical-align: top;` but as you can see that's not enough to make it OK in all browsers.

Comment: but assigning the VALIGN property in the TD itself (NOT CSS!) might fix it.

Comment: `valign` is deprecated and putting `vertical-align:top;" in style attribute does not do anything different from the css version. See the answer I added for a solution that **does** work (although it is a little intricate).

Answer (score 1):

What about configuring everything for Chrome and then putting conditional CSS statements for your IE CSS classes?:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<!--[if IE 9]>
```

That should do the work, though it may be not the best and optimized method ever. I remember having similar problem with text alignment and this helped me.

Sorry that I'm putting this into the answer and not comment but I still can't comment due to my reputation.

**EDIT**

For example:

Since I don't know for sure what_exact_parameters you should assign (you'll need to figure it out by yourself), I'll just give a dummy example:

**Inline**:

```
td {     
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 2px\0/; <!-- IE-8 only -->
}
```

**Target specific IE-only stylesheet**:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your-stylesheet-for-ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The problem here is that sometimes they fix those bugs and then your conditional statements not only become useless but may also make even more troubles. So I would recommend at least not put anything really *drastic* there, so that if they fix those bugs, your page wouldn't break down at all.

Here are couple of good links to read more about conditional CSS statements: 
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ 
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Comment: sounds promising - can you supply examples of conditional css (I did not know you could do that and have not seen any examples yet).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get buttons to style like a hyperlink is actually nigh on impossible in some browsers as they have so many stylistic shims in place in the browser stylesheet. If you can avoid using a button, I would advise it.

The reason for this is that in addition to padding and margin, browsers add other styles such as in Firefox:

```
button, input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -moz-binding: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

And you would have to reset everything that is affecting the layout in all browsers - after which the text may still not be in the right place as buttons seem to still push the text lower than you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons in some browsers are simply taller. This is ok — different browsers may display buttons somewhat differently. `vertical-align: top` on the TD is probably honoured, but the button is making your table row taller, which makes text on the left cell show misaligned since it's pushed to the top. As for IE7, I can't tell why is the button text so low, but hey, it's MSIE, it doesn't have to conform to anything or work at all.

Use `vertical-align: middle` if you want the text to align properly, or use line-height and/or padding to make the row equally as tall for everyone.